# Download planilha com Openpyxl

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

Estou com dificuldades para resolver esta questão. Já pesquisei bastante e ainda não encontrei uma solução para o problema.

Em Python, faço uso da biblioteca Openpyxl  para gerar uma planilha simples em Excel. Salvo no diretório local e tudo funciona bem com o código abaixo:

```
wb = Workbook()

 ws = wb.create_sheet(‘Dados’)

ws['A1'] = 'Nome'

ws['A2'] = 'Telefone'

wb.save()
```

Porém, gostaria que no momento que eu fosse salvar essa planilha, ao invés de salvar no diretório da aplicação, que o abrisse a janela de "Salvar Como" para o usuário escolher onde gostaria de salvar a sua planilha.

Pois essa planilha não pode ser gravado no diretório da aplicação, seja local ou no servidor, e sim o usuário escolherá seu local preferido para gravar.

Comment: Acredito que vc usa DJango uma vez que está na tag. Sendo assim, peço que coloque o urls.py, views.py e template caso exista.

Comment: O `openpyxl` não executa o excel. Ele cria a estrutura do arquivo no formato do excel sozinho. `openpyxl` não é uma ferramenta gráfica, não exibe nada na sua tela.
Se quer mostrar uma janela de "Salvar como", precisará usar alguma biblioteca de interface com o usuário, como `tkinter`, `gtk`, `kivy`, etc

Comment: Sim é verdade, ele não executa o Excel. Talvez eu não tenha conseguido explicar. Na minha aplicação, tenho um botão "Exportar" que chama aquela função e ai que seria a mágica. gostaria que no momento que este botão fosse clicado, este Excel fosse criada a estrutura e em seguida dá a opção ao usuário em qual o local ele gostaria de salvar como se fosse um procedimento de dowaload. Não sei se consegui ajudar com o esclarecimento.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ruim, ela foca no openpyxl que não tem nada a ver. O que você quer aprender é como mostrar uma pergunta pro usuário em HTML/Javascript no navegador, e receber o valor do lado do servidor

Comment: Por isso está recebendo essas respostas não relacionadas. Eu sugiro melhorar a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Leandro, tudo bem com você?

Como o pessoal comentou, o `tkinter` é uma boa opção, ele já costuma vir instalado no Python básico, então se for uma aplicação que roda localmente(no PC do usuário e não no navegador) você pode utiliza-lo.

```py
from tkinter import filedialog

filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()

print(filename)
```

O filename será o caminho do arquivo escolhido pelo usuário, acredito que o `save` do workbook possa receber o caminho. De uma conferida na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename) e faça alguns testes.

Comment: A ideia é muito boa. Mas a aplicação roda num servidor e não no local. Entendi que esta seria uma solução local apenas né!?

Answer (score 0):

uma solução possível é você definir o local onde deseja salvar o seu arquivo.

segue um exemplo espero que possa ajudá-lo.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.create_sheet('Dados')

ws['A1'] = 'Nome'

ws['A2'] = 'Telefone'

"""
* o nome do arquivo já deve ser seguido por .xlsx
* o path é o local onde você deseja salvar o arquivo. Informe
  o caminho e inverta as barras.

"""
nome_arquivo = input(str('Digite um nome para o arquivo'))
path = input(str('Onde deseja salvar?'))
wb.save(path+nome_arquivo)
```

Comment: Seria uma boa saída a sua solução. Mas a aplicação funciona num servidor e ai não iria conseguir salvar no local do usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a resposta para o que eu precisava galera. Muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos.

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&pto=aue&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&sp=nmt4&tl=pt&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217306/return-openpyxl-workbook-object-as-httpresponse-in-django-is-it-possible&usg=ALkJrhib0niStaaoZyM-2ALEf6sx34o-qg